# SQL server & Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I need help with SQL server in visual studio. I can't seem to connect my visual studio with internal SQL server. I had created a database with visual studio earlier and it was working fine but now i'm getting an error saying:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following
>   information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
>   Application event log for error details.

I have tried to create a new database file in a new project but then i get the error:

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. (Provider:Named Pipes Provider, error:40- could not open a
>   connection to SQL server.

I have tried different things but can't seem to get the hang of the problem. I reinstalled visual studio too but that didn't work either. what can i do to get rid of this error and get my database back online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Visual Studio on your local machine, you have not any problem with firewalls and enabling of TCP/IP.

Try this four solutions may fix your problem:

1. SQL Server Express LocalDB add-on, get it from [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) link.
2. Make sure that your [SQL service is running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx#SSCMProcedure).
3. Use SQL Server Authentication.
4. Make sure you have typed `.\sqlexpress` in Server name in Add Connection window. You should use a backslash `\` as the separator, not a forward slash.